# Estou com problema para salvar o conteúdo de um docx em pdf

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, jaxb

Tenho um método Rest que pega um documento do Word, substitui os espaços reservados e converte o mesmo em PDF e salva em um diretório. Mas estou com um NullPointerException que não consegui resolver, alguem pode ajudar?

Log Error:

```
14:35:11,134 ERROR [org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter] (default task-24) Exception exporting package: org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Missing WordprocessingMLPackage in the conversion settings
at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractWmlExporter.preprocess(AbstractWmlExporter.java:49)
at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractWmlExporter.preprocess(AbstractWmlExporter.java:32)
at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:64)
at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toFO(Docx4J.java:466)
at br.com.qative.qimob.docx.Load$1.write(Load.java:170)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:32)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:17)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:129)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:62)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:118)
at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalSigningInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(DigitalSigningInterceptor.java:143)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:122)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPEncodingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(GZIPEncodingInterceptor.java:100)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:122)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:99)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:427)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:376)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at br.com.qative.qimob.seguranca.FiltroControleAcesso.doFilter(FiltroControleAcesso.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

```
14:35:11,150 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-24) UT005023: Exception handling request to /api/docx/fichaCaptacao: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: Response is committed, can't handle exception
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:432)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:376)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at br.com.qative.qimob.seguranca.FiltroControleAcesso.doFilter(FiltroControleAcesso.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at br.com.qative.qimob.docx.Load$1.write(Load.java:172)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:32)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:17)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:129)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:62)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:118)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalSigningInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(DigitalSigningInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:122)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPEncodingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(GZIPEncodingInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:122)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:99)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:427)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Exception exporting package
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:109)
    at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toFO(Docx4J.java:466)
    at br.com.qative.qimob.docx.Load$1.write(Load.java:170)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Missing WordprocessingMLPackage in the conversion settings
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractWmlExporter.preprocess(AbstractWmlExporter.java:49)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractWmlExporter.preprocess(AbstractWmlExporter.java:32)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:64)
    ... 54 more
```

Método que realiza a operação descrita lá no inicio:

```
@Path("fichaCaptacao")
@GET
@Produces({"application/pdf"})
public Response fichaCaptacao(@Context ServletContext servletContext) throws Exception {
    String regex = null;
    //regex=".*(Courier New|Arial|Times New Roman|Comic Sans|Georgia|Impact|Lucida Console|Lucida Sans Unicode|Palatino Linotype|Tahoma|Trebuchet|Verdana|Symbol|Webdings|Wingdings|MS Sans Serif|MS Serif).*";

    PhysicalFonts.setRegex(regex);

    InputStream docxInputStream = new FileInputStream(servletContext.getRealPath("/") + "/resources/templates/contratos/CONTRATO DE ADMINISTRAÇÃO.docx");

    final WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage;
    WordprocessingMLPackage tmpPkg = null;
    String docxname = "CONTRATO DE ADMINISTRAÇÃO.docx";

    try {
        tmpPkg = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(docxInputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(new Docx4JException("Não foi possível ler o docx modelo"), Status.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    MainDocumentPart documentPart = tmpPkg.getMainDocumentPart();

    HashMap<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<>();
    mappings.put("contratante", "Pedro Isaac");
    mappings.put("naturalidade", "Goiás-GO");
    mappings.put("nacionalidade", "Brasileiro");
    mappings.put("estadoCivil", " ");
    mappings.put("profissao", "Analista de Sistemas");
    mappings.put("sexo", "Masculino");
    mappings.put("email", " ");
    mappings.put("cpf", " ");
    mappings.put("rg", " ");
    mappings.put("orgaoExpedidor", " ");
    mappings.put("tipoEndereco", "Sobrado");
    mappings.put("endereco", " ");
    mappings.put("numero", " ");
    mappings.put("quadra", " ");
    mappings.put("energia", "");
    mappings.put("bairro", " ");
    mappings.put("cidade", " ");
    mappings.put("estado", " ");
    mappings.put("cep", " ");
    mappings.put("telefone", " ");
    mappings.put("celular", " ");
    mappings.put("telComercial", " ");
    mappings.put("conjuge", " ");

    documentPart.variableReplace(mappings);

    FieldUpdater updater = new FieldUpdater(tmpPkg);
    updater.update(true);

    PhysicalFont font = PhysicalFonts.get("Arial Unicode MS");

    final FOSettings foSettings = Docx4J.createFOSettings();
    String outputfilepath;
    outputfilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/OUT_FontContent.pdf";
    OutputStream os = new java.io.FileOutputStream(outputfilepath);

    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok(
            new StreamingOutput() {
                public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                    try {
                        // Don't care what type of exporter you use
                        Docx4J.toFO(foSettings, output, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);
                    } catch (Docx4JException e) {
                        throw new WebApplicationException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
    );

    return builder.build();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema. A questão é que o JBoss buscava algumas dependências dele mesmo, daí tive que adicionar duas dependências referente ao JaxB. As dependências segue abaixo:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
```